# Override a css value from a third party lib

Tags: css

I'm using a third party `css` library for styling, but I'd like to specify a different `min-height` for a particular `div`.
The `div` is using `themeRow` class which has a number of attributes and sets:

```
min-height: 200px
```

In my case this is much too large, and i'd like to set a different value i.e

```
min-height: 75px
```

So i've defined some inline `css` but my value is being ruled out when rendered and the `div` still draws at `min-height: 200px`

Any way I can tell `css` to use my value instead of the third party value?

```
<style>
.bannerHeight {
    min-height: 75px;
}
</style>


<div class="themeRow bannerHeight"></div>
```

Comment: That's a case for CSS `!important`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `!important` to override the `min-height: 200px` value which is being assigned to your `<div>` by the third-party library. Try using this CSS:

```
<style>
.bannerHeight {
    min-height: 75px !important;
}
</style>
```

Comment: is it possible to remove min-height set by the third party js?

Answer (score 8):

IMHO it is better to use deeper levels over `!important`. If this is on your page 'main' then

```
<style>
.main .bannerHeight {
    min-height: 75px;
}
</style>
```

will override

```
<style>
.bannerHeight {
    min-height: 75px;
}
</style>
```

simply replace `.main` with whatever element is the parent to `.bannerHeight`, possibly just `div .bannerHeight` in this case as you hint. `!important` should be used for awkward situations where html css elements are being created dynamically, not for simple CSS overwriting as in this case.

But its your call.

Answer (score 3):

There is an inherent hierarchy (hence the "cascading") within the style sheets that can help you solve this issue (More on it here: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html and here: http://www.w3.org/TR/css-cascade-3/)

Essentially, if you want to "overwrite" a rule you can:

- place the desired rule lower in the existing stylesheet (author sheet)
- Create a new stylesheet, and call it lower on the page (second author sheet)
- use the important tag (as mentioned above) (overrides other calls)
- use inline styling (not entirely recommended as it combines "form" with "function" these should be separate entities)